# Creating feature dataset by pgAdmin (PostgreSQL) that can be useD in ArcSDE connection?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, pgadmin-3

How to create feature dataset in PostgreSQL (pgAdmin) that can by use in ArcSDE conection (ArcGIS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any table in the instance can be registered with sde.
But sde is what has to do that registration.
I suggest starting with this [Essential Reading for Geodatabases](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Essential_readings_about_the_geodatabase/003n00000003000000/)
[Registering with the database](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Registering_a_table_with_the_geodatabase/003n000000qz000000/)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Brad - pgAdmin cannot create SDE Services -

You need to use the command line of:

> sdeconfig

http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/whnjs.htm

Useful reference:
Setting up a geodatabase in PostgreSQL
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p00000001000000

PostgreSQL client libraries are required on the client computer from which you will connect to the database.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p0000003q000000

Answer (score 0):

One thing: If you have configured your connection to ArcSDE in ArcCatalog (or ArcMap), another thing that you can do is creating the Feature Dataset you need by right-clicking on the database connection name, then clicking "New" and then "Feature Dataset". Like this, ArcSDE should create in your PostgreSQL database the dataset you need.

I have to say that I have never tried this operation with "Feature dataset", but I tried it with "View" *(and on SQL Server)* and it works, so it should work with Postgres too...

And don't forget to take a look at ["Geodatabase Administration" toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000009000000), new in ArcGIS 10.1 to do some operations in your geodatabase.